# Unexpected behavior overriding getWorkbenchErrorHandler in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I think I've discovered a kind of Schrödinger's cat problem in my code. The body of a function is never executed if I change one line within the body of that same function; but if I leave that line alone, the function executes. Somehow the program knows ahead of time what the body is, and decides not to call it...

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP application in Java, and have need to use their [Error Handling System](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI_Error_Handling). According to the page linked,

> There are two ways for adding handlers to the handling flow.
>
> - using extension point org.eclipse.ui.statusHandlers
> - by the workbench advisor and its method {@link WorkbenchAdvisor#getWorkbenchErrorHandler()}.

So I've gone into my `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` class, and overridden the `getWorkbenchErrorHandler` method:

```
@Override
public synchronized AbstractStatusHandler getWorkbenchErrorHandler()
{
    System.out.println("IT LIVES!");

    if (myErrorHandler == null)
    {
        AbstractStatusHandler delegate = super.getWorkbenchErrorHandler();
        MyStatusHandler otherThing = new MyStatusHandler(delegate);
        myErrorHandler = otherThing;
    }
    return myErrorHandler;
}
```

The `MyStatusHandler` is meant to act as a wrapper for the `delegate` handler. I've re-named the class for anonymity. As it is, above, this function is never called. The println never happens, and even in debug mode with breakpoints, they never trigger. Now the wierd part: If I change the line that assigns the `myErrorHandler` to

```
myErrorHandler = delegate;
```

then the function *is* called; multiple times, in fact!

This problem has me and two java-savvy coworkers stumped, so I'm hoping the good people of SO can help us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, my problem was that the `MyErrorHandler` class was defined in a different plugin, which presumably wasn't fully loaded yet. That doesn't seem to add up entirely, but once I moved the class definition of my error handler into the same plugin that was calling it during startup, the problems went away.